# TextBox TextMode = Time -> always show seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use asp Textboxes with `TextMode='Time'`  but it won't show the seconds correctly, especially when they are *00* and if there are some seconds you can't edit them because they are grayed out.

[image]

[image]

**How can I set the textbox for accepting *hh:mm:ss***?

I tried a few things which didn't work, like:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDuration" TextMode="Time"  format="HH:mm:ss" CssClass="elementsmall" />
```

I wanted to use TextMode so I do not need to control if the input is a time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`step` attribute](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#step):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbDuration" TextMode="Time" step="1"  format="HH:mm:ss" CssClass="elementsmall" />
```

That's not an ASP.NET- but HTML 5 attribute.